# jQuery check hidden elements and use its data

Tags: jquery, hidden, element

I am trying to achieve something here. Once I click a link, the value of a hidden element specified for that link will be set to 1 (0 by default). This works fine.

Next step, I am looping through all hidden elements to see which ones are set to 1. If it is set to 1, I add its ID to a variable. The next one that is set to 1, its ID needs to be put in the same variable behind it.

So the variable with the IDs should look like: hidden1/hidden2/hidden3

It is hard to explain, but here I reconstructed it:
http://jsfiddle.net/UgbMx/

Once I click the the SUBMIT button, it looks up if it is 1 or 0 just fine. Then it loops through the hidden elements. It recongizes that the element is either set to 1 or 0. After that, it goes wrong.

Comment: `After that, it goes wrong` - you realize it's so vague that no one has a clue except you what "wrong" is in this case?

Comment: If I would have a clue myself, I would explain it a little better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the var statement before test_total inside the callbacks and you will be fine! You are re-declaring the test_total variable within the each-callback scope.

So this part is changed (I truncated the comment for readability):

```
            if (test_total == "EMPTY") {
                test_total = $(this).attr("id") + "/SEPERATOR/";
            // In case the variable [...]
            } else {
                test_total = test_total + $(this).attr("id") + "/SEPERATOR/";
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can substantially shorten your solution:

```
test_total = $(".test_item[value='1']").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get().join("/separator/");
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/UgbMx/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the scope you're using `var` to declare a new scope, thus resetting the variable `test_total` see [the updated fiddle for a working version](http://jsfiddle.net/UgbMx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the var test_total three times. You need to remove "var " from the beginning of the two lines inside the each loop. Once you remove that, it works great... like you would expect.

```
var test_total = "EMPTY";

    // Check every hidden element with the classname "test_item".
    $(".test_item").each(function() {

        // Check if the hidden element is changed to 1 (link clicked).
        if ($(this).val() == "1") {
            // In case the variable we just made is still EMPTY, empty it and add the ID + Seperator
            if (test_total == "EMPTY") {
                test_total = $(this).attr("id") + "/SEPERATOR/";
            // In case the variable is not EMPTY anymore, use the previous entries and add a new ID+Seperator
            } else {
                test_total = test_total + $(this).attr("id") + "/SEPERATOR/";
            }
            alert("Variable test_total is now:\n" + test_total);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are totally right, you're redeclaring the test total loads. The code in general could be shrunk way down though. E.g.,

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="test1" class="test_item" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" id="test2" class="test_item" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" id="test3" class="test_item" value="0" />

<a href="#" class="HiddenFieldLink" data-hidden-field="test1">- Click me to check button 1</a><br />
<a href="#" class="HiddenFieldLink" data-hidden-field="test2">- Click me to check button 2</a><br />
<a href="#" class="HiddenFieldLink" data-hidden-field="test3">- Click me to check button 3</a><br />
<br /><br />
<a href="#" id="test_submit">Submit this</a>
```

I've put a class on the links instead of an ID, removed the javascript href and given the items a data- attribute to indicate their matching field.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Text for button 1 clicked.
    $(".HiddenFieldLink").live('click', function(e) {
        var link = $(this),
            hiddenField = link.data('hiddenField');
        // BUTTON CLICKED
        $('#' + hiddenField ).val("1");
        // CHANGE TEXT
        link.text("Button clicked");

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // The tricky party
    $("#test_submit").live('click', function() {
        var test_total = "EMPTY",
            entries = $.map($(".test_item"), function(item) {
                if(item.value === '1') {
                    return item.id;
                }
            });

        if(entries.length) {
            test_total = entries.join("/SEPERATOR/");
        }

        // Show me the output.
        alert("Variable test_total is now:\n" + test_total);
    });
});
```

Now we only need one event handler for all the links which modify the hidden fields.  Additionally the e.preventDefault(); stops the link trying to do anything (nicer than blank javascript).

Finally I've switched the submit statement to use the jQuery $.map() function, this returns an array of items returned from the function provided as a second argument.  This can then be joined with your seperator.

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvP53/).